# BAT file cammand does not work

Tags: batch-file

I can open cmd window and I can execute following command, it asks me for password.

```
net use w: /delete
For /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %A in ('arp -a ^| findstr -i 00-d0-b8-20-f7-67') do net use w: \\%A\Pictures /USER:EKFAKE
```

I want to put this in bat file and I want to keep cmd window open. Tried various ways but failed to get this going.

Please help. Thanks.

***EDIT***

I tried following way but uid and password is not taken and it does not connect to the drive.

```
SET /P _inputname= Please enter an username: 

SET /P _inputpass= Please enter an password: 

For /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%A in ('arp -a ^| findstr -i 00-d0-b8-20-f7-67') do net use w: \%%A\Pictures \user:%_inputname% %_inputpass%
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] before you ask anymore questions, be sure to read [Ask] and [MCVE].

Comment: `\user:...` ? Wasn't that `/user:...`?

Answer (score 2):

```
net use w: /delete
For /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%A in ('arp -a ^| findstr -i 00-d0-b8-20-f7-67') do net use w: \%%A\Pictures /USER:EKFAKE
pause
```

Note the use of `%%` for the metavariable `A`. `%%` is required within a batchfile, `%` direct from the prompt.

Your code, in a batch file, will generate a syntax-error. which will be reported to the screen. If you are clicking on the file to run it, the error is shown then the process closes. You would see the syntax-error message if you were running the batch from the prompt.

The `pause` instruction will leave the window open - but **not** if `cmd` finds a syntax error - you need to run from the prompt to see those.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
The batch command does not stop to prompt for password. How to make batch file so that it will prompt for password ?

For /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%A in ('arp -a ^| findstr -i 00-d0-b8-20-f7-67') do net use w: \%%A\Pictures /USER:EKFAKE

Comment: @SJain edit the question and put the necessary information. And use backticks to format code `\`like this\`` or no one can read that

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution based on your edit. Please do not mark this answer as correct as @Magoo gave you the correct solution already.

```
@echo off
SET /P _inputname=Please enter your username:
SET /P _inputpass=Please enter your password:
For /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%A in ('arp -a ^| findstr -i 00-d0-b8-20-f7-67') do (net use w: \\%%A\Pictures /user:%_inputname% %_inputpass%)
```

Comment: The net use command does no work as expected here. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: @SJain, in the absence of any indication of your actual results and expectations.  "does not work" is an inadequate problem statement.

Comment: Did you copy my script exactly?